# Nested Quote for return confirm('Are you sure?')

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
return  '<form action="'.route('own_product_delete', $product_datatable['id']).'" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" /><input type="hidden" name="_token" value="'.csrf_token() .'"><button type="submit" onclick="return confirm()" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></form>';
```

I have used single quote for php and double quote for html but how to write inside `return confirm()`? I mean I need to write `return confirm('Are you Sure>')`
complexity is, it's inside single quote for php and then double quote for html `'onclick="return confirm()"'` I am not able to use any quote for confirm message. Please suggest me

Comment: Just escape for the PHP single quotes `onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure?\')"`

Comment: it's works. Thank you so much for your replay :)

Comment: YW. Feel free to delete the question